# Appending to the front of for statement output

Tags: python

I have this code;

```
   offset = -0
    print ("In Command 3 - Brute force")
    string = input("Please enter a string to Brute Force:")
    while offset > -26:
        offset = offset - 1
        print("")
        for letter in string:
            letter = (ord(letter))
            letter = letter + offset
            if letter > 126:
                letter - 95
            elif letter < 32:
                letter + 32
            output = (chr(letter))
            print(output,end='')
            choice = 0
```

Output depending on the string something like this;

```
rc`rcr
qb_qbq
pa^pap
o`]o`o
n_\n_n
m^[m^m
l]Zl]l
k\Yk\k
j[Xj[j
iZWiZi
hYVhYh
gXUgXg
fWTfWf
eVSeVe
dURdUd
cTQcTc
bSPbSb
aROaRa
`QN`Q`
_PM_P_
^OL^O^
]NK]N]
\MJ\M\
[LI[L[
ZKHZKZ
YJGYJY
```

Now, I need some text before the output for example;

```
Decryption string rc`rcr
Decryption string qb_qbq
```

etc...

I have tried;

```
print("Decryption",output,end='')
```

and

```
print("Decryption"+output,end='')
```

However this gives me that text in front of every letter.

Please assist if you can, and explanation would also be preferred.

Thanks for your time.

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
offset = -0
print ("In Command 3 - Brute force")
string = input("Please enter a string to Brute Force:")
while offset > -26:
    offset = offset - 1
    word = ""
    for letter in string:
        letter = (ord(letter))
        letter = letter + offset
        if letter > 126:
            letter - 95
        elif letter < 32:
            letter + 32
        output = (chr(letter))
        word = word + output            
        choice = 0
    print("Decryption: "+word)
```

The problem with what you were trying is that it will print the 'Decrypting:' message for each character not for each word, so you need to build the word before printing it.

Comment: Yer great man thanks, I was fiddling around with something like that i just couldn't get it rite,Its blatantly obvious when i look at it now tetee. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the output letter by letter, so adding `print("Decryption"+output,end='')` will just add the 'Decryption' part to each printout. I suggest doing a:

```
print("Decryption" + string, end=' ')
```

before you start your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your output string and then print it after the for loop

```
   offset = -0
    print ("In Command 3 - Brute force")
    string = input("Please enter a string to Brute Force:")
    while offset > -26:
        offset = offset - 1
        output_final = None
        for letter in string:
            letter = (ord(letter))
            letter = letter + offset
            if letter > 126:
                letter - 95
            elif letter < 32:
                letter + 32
            output_final += (chr(letter))
            choice = 0
        print 'Description:', output_final
```